# Show/Hidden form when edit data

Tags: javascript, laravel

i need some help.
I making show/hidden form based on checkbox in Laravel. When i create data it's worked, but when i will edit data, form not hidden when checkbox is checked.

It's my **view.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="{{ Auth::user()->address ? }}">

<input type="checkbox" name="same_address" id="same_address" value="Ya" {{ Auth::user()->same_address == 'Ya' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Domicile is same

<div id="hidden_fields>
    <input type="text" name="domicile" id="domicile" value="{{ Auth::user()->domicile  }}">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Js Show/Hide Form
    $(function() {
        var checkbox = $("#same_address");
        var hidden = $("#hidden_fields");
        hidden.show();
        checkbox.change(function() {
            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                hidden.hide();
            } else {
                hidden.show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition like that.

[jquery `hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method add the style "display: none;"

```
<div id="hidden_fields" @if(Auth::user()->same_address == 'Ya') style="display: none;" @endif>
    <input type="text" name="domicile" id="domicile" value="{{ Auth::user()->domicile  }}">
</div>
```